# A general question: how to find zero divisors in the polynomial ring?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Just a theoretical question for now. without the exercise itself. Let $Z[x]$ be the ring and some ideal $I$. $I$ can be factored to (for example) 2 prime polynomials.

Are they any other zero divisors (none trivial), beside the prime polynomials which are the factorization of I?

As I understand the factored polynomials are defintly none-trivial zero divisors, because there multiply gives us I and modulo I it is 0, but none of them is 0.

Comment: Are you speaking of zero-divisors modulo $I$?

Comment: Yes, and you right, I should mention it. Zero-divisors at the quotient-ring modulo $I$.

Comment: You seem to gorgt $\mathbf Z[x]$ is *not*  a PID. In general there is no factorisation of $I$.

Comment: Yes, you right about the PID. In my concrete example, i'll be accurate, it is Z3[x] and I is a polynomial that can be factored to 2 polynomials. I=x3+2x2+2=(x+1)(x2+x+2)

Comment: I've written  an answer to your comment. Perhaps you should incorporate it to your question, so that the answer be easily understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring $ R=\mathbf Z_3[x]/(x^3+2x^2+2)$ has only two prime ideals $(x+1)R$  and $(x^2+2x+2)R$, since in $\mathbf Z_3[x]$, they  are the irreducible factors of $x^3+2x^2+2$. Thus $ R$ is a semi-local ring of Krull dimension $0$. Its zero-divisors is the union of the two prime ideals in $\operatorname{Ass}R=\operatorname{Spec}R$.